# cleatInterval() not stoping setInterval() in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongoose, chatbot, facebook-chatbot

I'm working on facebook bot in node.js (new to node.js) and i have problem.
When user sends last message i need to detect it and set reminder (let's sy it should remind person in one minute)

```
if(!candidate.finished){
                clearTimeout(JSON.parse(candidate.timerId));
                var t = setTimeout(()=>{
                    candidate.timerId = JSON.stringify(t)
                    console.log("STRINGIFY " + candidate.timerId)
                    candidate.save();
                    sendQuickReplies(sender,"Do you want to continue application process?",['Yes','No'],token);
                }, 60000);
 }
```

problem is that clearTimeout do not kill setTimeout when user sends another message (when user sends another message this function is being called all over again and it shoutld stop previous timer and start new one)
This code remindes person in one minute but it wont stop reminding

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare your timer `var t = setTimeout(() => {...}, 60000);` before you call `clearTimeout` and use `clearTimeout` on the variable `t`. In your code snippet, `clearTimeout` isn't referencing the timer variable `t`.

So something like this should work instead:

```
var t = setTimeout(() => {...}, 60000);
clearTimeout(t);
```

and your 1 min timer will be cancelled.

In the context of your question, I suppose you want to stop the reminder timer from executing once the user has sent you a message. So you just need to keep track of your timer variable `t` when you start your timer and once the required message is received, stop that timer `t` with `clearTimeout(t)`. That way, the correct reference to the timer will be stopped and the user won't be reminded repeatedly.